# Redoing a Git merge already buried in history without changing history

Tags: git

I tried the answer at https://superuser.com/a/1219061/108993, but either I wasn't understanding it correctly or it doesn't work in my case. In my case branch `A` merged from `main` a few days ago and improperly included some additional changes. It was treated (possibly by the developer) as a normal commit instead of a merge commit, meaning all the changes from main were discarded and the desired changes were committed, but the history records this as a merge commit with 2 parents. Then a merge from `main` was re-attempted (and committed) of course failing to update any of the files whose changes were discarded in the first merge.

I devised a process, but it has a couple shortcomings:

1. It's kind of tedious,
2. I think it lacks a common ancestor for part of the process (it's a baseless merge?), which causes deleted code to be re-introduced, requiring manual intervention.

## Steps

1. Use `git merge-base` to identify the **base** commit on which the bad merge's parents were based
2. Use `git diff` to generate a patch file from **base** to the **parent** on the `main` branch (the changes that were excluded from the faulty merge commit)
3. Checkout the **base** commit
4. Use `git apply my.patch` to copy the changes into my worktree
5. Stash the changes applied by the patch
6. Checkout the tip of branch `A`
7. Apply/pop the stash
8. Resolve conflicts
9. Manually correct errors due to lack of common ancestor (delete code that was supposed to be deleted,but got re-introduced by the base-less diff/apply)
10. Commit

Is there an easier or more reliable way to re-apply the changes between **base** and the **parent** commit originally from main?

Comment: The cleanest way to do it is to reset before the faulty merge, do a clean merge, then cherry-pick the commits that were done after the faulty merge. It 'rewrite' history but you got a clean history at the end.

Comment: I like the idea of rewriting history but if people are already working on top of it, it is not recommended to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is this:

- retry the bad merge (merge the same 2 parents). Do it correctly this time. Finish the merge on a commit. Let's say it is commit `X`
- use a soft reset on top of the *old* bad merge and commit.... this way, git will understand that you want to reintroduce these files that got changes "taken back".
- feel free to merge this commit into the main branch to get that code back.

So, it goes something like this:

```
git checkout parent1
git merge parents # fix conflicts, finish the merge, get your new commit
git reset --soft the-old-bad-merge
git commit -m "getting changes back"
git branch some-branch
```

Now you can merge `some-branch` where you need it. This has the downside of not keeping history of those changes that were *removed* on the busted commit. If you want to do it *correctly*, then it requires a little bit more work. There are 2 parents to your busted commit.... one is a feature branch, the other is a commit from the main branch. Identify this parent from main branch and let's call it `Pmain`. So.... do the same trick of creating the new merge commit that we did before with the 2 parent commits:

```
git checkout parent1
git merge parents # fix conflicts, finish the merge, get your new commit
```

Now, instead of doing a soft-reset, let's use the *contents* of this commit to create a new commit that has the broken merge commit as parent and `Pmain` as the other parent.... this commit does *not* have the changes removed and, to git, it is past the broken merge commit so it would *think* that it needs to add the lines of you merge it in `main` branch:

```
git commit-tree -p bad-merge-commit -p Pmain -m "Keeping changes past the busted merge commit" @^{tree}
```

This will print a commit ID... this commit is your savior to keep history of those reverted changes. Give it a try... try to blame *on that commit* one of the files that got its content reverted back. The lines should be there *and* it should tell you the original commit where the change was put it. If that is the case, you should be able to merge this commit into main branch and those lines should come back to life in `main` and the history should be connected to the original commits (check again with blame).

Comment: I'm confused on the last code sample. I substituted commit hashes for bad-merge-commit and Pmain, but I'm not sure what `@^{tree}` is. Is that literally what I should pass in? When I tried I got `fatal: not a valid object name @{tree}`

Comment: It is literally `@^{tree}`. That means: the tree from `HEAD`. Another way: `HEAD^{tree}`.

Comment: I'm still getting `fatal: not a valid object name HEAD{tree}` and I'm not sure why the error message doesn't include the `^`.

Comment: If you are you working in Command Prompt, you have to double the caret.

Comment: If I run `git commit-tree` and lost track of the commit that it reported (or did something essentially similar to git-commit-tree resulting in similarly "orphaned" commits), is there in fact some orphan/hidden commit out there? Is there any way to find such commit(s) and clean them up?

Comment: They will be cleaned up someday when `git gc` runs as it won't be linked to any reference.

Comment: So, which approach did you follow?

Comment: The developer followed my original approach in my question. I think this ends us up somewhere similar to your first suggestion with the soft reset and commit to a new branch, which can then be merged into the initial branch. I think that's fine because I think the history is still there, just obscured by an extra change. I tried your last solution with commit-tree and I think I didn't end up with all the changes, so I might have screwed it up, misinterpreted the results or it doesn't work the way I need it to. But I feel safer with the earlier solution that I think I understand and works well.

Comment: It turns out, BTW, that there were not merge errors that needed to be corrected even in my original steps. I thought there were, but the developer says everything was fine. So I guess I don't know if your first solution is better than mine except in its simplicity.

Comment: Oh, but even with your first solution, I got a little lost on the reset because the commit I thought you were referring to did not appear to be a valid commit to reset to from that state (using VS Code w/ GitLens). So I think I simply used --no-commit on the merge and created a new branch before committing, then merged from that branch to the original branch.